# Check for specific value in array typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this array,

```js
[
    about: "INVALID"
    team: "VALID"
]
```

I want to check if the array contains at least one `INVALID` value then return `false`. This is what I've tried

```js
if (this.forms.indexOf('INVALID') > -1) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

But it is not working and it is always returning `true`. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: That _"array"_ is invalid syntax

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the object syntax, you can do the following:

```js
const forms = {
    about: "INVALID",
    team: "VALID"
};

console.log(Object.values(forms).includes('INVALID'));
```

Simply use `Object.values` to get the collection of values and `Array.includes` to find a value inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object you could check it this way.

```
let obj = {
    about: "VALID",
    team: "INVALID"
}

var hasInvalid = Object.keys(obj).some(el => obj[el] === 'INVALID');
```

**hasInvalid** returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for both array and object

```
if(JSON.stringify(this.forms).includes('INVALID')){
    return false;
}
return true;
```